# Using python requests to mask as a browser and download a file

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use the python requests library to download a file from this link:
http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download

Clicking on this link will give you a file (nasdaq.csv) only when using a browser. I used the Firefox Network Monitor Ctrl-Shift-Q to retrieve all the headers that Firefox sends. So now I finally get a 200 server response but still no file. The file that this script produces contains parts of the Nasdaq website, not the csv data. I looked at similar questions on this site and nothing leads me to believe that this shouldn't be possible with the requests library.

Code:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download"

# Fake Firefox headers 
headers = {"Host" : "www.nasdaq.com", \
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0", \
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", \
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", \
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", \
        "DNT": "1", \
        "Cookie": "clientPrefs=||||lightg; userSymbolList=EOD+&DIT; userCookiePref=true; selectedsymbolindustry=EOD,; selectedsymboltype=EOD,EVERGREEN GLOBAL DIVIDEND OPPORTUNITY FUND COMMON SHARES OF BENEFICIAL INTEREST,NYSE; c_enabled$=true", \
        "Connection": "keep-alive", }

# Get the list
response = requests.get(url, headers, stream=True)
print(response.status_code)

# Write server response to file
with open("nasdaq.csv", 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to supply any headers:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download"

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
print(response.status_code)

# Write server response to file
with open("nasdaq.csv", 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
```

You can also just write the content:

```
import requests

# Write server response to file
with open("nasdaq.csv", 'wb') as f:
       f.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

Or use urlib:

```
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download","nasdaq.csv")
```

All  methods give you the 3137 line csv file:

```
"Symbol","Name","LastSale","MarketCap","ADR TSO","IPOyear","Sector","Industry","Summary Quote",
"TFSC","1347 Capital Corp.","9.79","58230920","n/a","2014","Finance","Business Services","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/tfsc",
"TFSCR","1347 Capital Corp.","0.15","0","n/a","2014","Finance","Business Services","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/tfscr",
"TFSCU","1347 Capital Corp.","10","41800000","n/a","2014","Finance","Business Services","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/tfscu",
"TFSCW","1347 Capital Corp.","0.178","0","n/a","2014","Finance","Business Services","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/tfscw",
"PIH","1347 Property Insurance Holdings, Inc.","7.51","46441171.61","n/a","2014","Finance","Property-Casualty Insurers","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/pih",
"FLWS","1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc.","7.87","510463090.04","n/a","1999","Consumer Services","Other Specialty Stores","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/flws",
"FCTY","1st Century Bancshares, Inc","7.81","80612492.62","n/a","n/a","Finance","Major Banks","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fcty",
"FCCY","1st Constitution Bancorp (NJ)","12.39","93508122.96","n/a","n/a","Finance","Savings Institutions","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fccy",
"SRCE","1st Source Corporation","30.54","796548769.38","n/a","n/a","Finance","Major Banks","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/srce",
"VNET","21Vianet Group, Inc.","20.26","1035270865.78","51099253","2011","Technology","Computer Software: Programming, Data Processing","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/vnet",
   ...................................
```

If for some reason it does not work for you then you might need to upgrade your version of requests.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need those headers. You don't even need to save to a file.

```
import requests
import csv

url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download"
response = requests.get(url)
data = csv.DictReader(response.content.splitlines())
for row in data:
    print row
```

Sample output:

```
{'Sector': 'Technology', 'LastSale': '2.46', 'Name': 'Zynga Inc.', '': '', 'Summary Quote': 'http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/znga', 'Symbol': 'ZNGA', 'Industry': 'EDP Services', 'MarketCap': '2295110123.7', 'IPOyear': '2011', 'ADR TSO': 'n/a'}
```

You can use `csv.reader` instead of `DictReader` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, and shorter, solution for this problem would be:

```
import urllib

downloadFile = urllib.URLopener()
downloadFile.retrieve("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download", "companylist.csv")
```

This code uses the URL Library to create URL Request object (`downloadFile`) and then it retrieves the data from the NASDAQ link and saves it as `companylist.csv`.

According to the Python documentation, if you want to send a custom User-Agent (such as the Firefox User-Agent), you can subclass `URLopener` and set the `version` attribute to the user-agent you would like to use.

**Note**: *According to the Python documentation, as of Python v3.3, `urllib.URLopener()` is deprecated. As such, it may eventually be removed from the Python standards. However, as of Python v3.6 (Dev), `urllib.URLopener()` is still supported as a legacy interface.*