# Is it possible for requests.Response.iter_content to return empty chunks?

Tags: python, python-requests

In many StackOverflow questions and answers like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243835/using-python-requests-to-mask-as-a-browser-and-download-a-file/34244483), or ..., and many other places all around the web, people are using the following pattern to retrieve results using `iter_content`:

```
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512 * 1024): 
    if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        f.write(chunk)
```

But is the `if chunk:` condition really necessary, especially when the chunk size is a positive integer like here?

Doesn't the underlying code already handle this case? To me, it seems that it does, see [3](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/24092b11d74af0a766d9cc616622f38adb0044b9/requests/models.py#L757), [4](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/response.py#L438)...

Is it still a good practice to check for empty chunks?

P.S. I know that the requests docs suggest to do this [for `iter_lines`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests):

```
for line in r.iter_lines():

    # filter out keep-alive new lines
    if line:
```

This question is only about `iter_content`.

### Update

It's also interesting to look at this the other way:

- [BytesIO.write in Python 3 won't try to write an empty buffer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13a6c098c215921e35004f9d3a9b70f601e56500/Modules/_io/bytesio.c#L680) and is essentially a no-op.
- In Python 2 it [calls fwrite](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8b9995f2ae0f9496de8a1a64a00d0681edd692bf/Objects/fileobject.c#L1871) but [fwrite in glibc has a check for empty buffers](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/d9ff799a5b2884d2abc0a1689fb6b2c71084424c/libio/iofwrite.c#L35) (don't know about other implementations though)

Thus people should probably not worry about these things, even when writing to a file using `iter_lines`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are entirely correct, testing if `chunk` is non-empty is redundant. The entire codepath in `requests` and `urllib3` *already* ensures that you are only served non-empty chunks.

The underlying code does need to check for empty chunks; those can be caused by network delays and / or decompression (where not enough data has yet arrived to decompress another block).